# Licenças de Software

Tags: java, licença

Tenho a seguinte duvida em relação ao uso de licenças de software.

Hoje como é feito e de que modo é mais usado a criação de licenças de uso de um software, destacando que eu tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Desktop.

Gostaria das dicas de que se existe alguma ferramenta ou método para criação de tais licenças e como fazer que elas expirem depois de um certo tempo.

Eu estou comercializando meu software por um valor mensal, e nesta licença eu gostaria de fazer o bloqueio por máquina e por tempo determinado.

Comment: Você quer criar a licença ou escolher a melhor licença para o seu projeto? Expirar??? Você quer licenciar o software ou você quer desenvolver um programa ShareWare?

Comment: Sua pergunta é ampla demais. Não sei se você está perguntando sobre tipos de licença, ou sobre a proteção do software em si. Existem inúmeros métodos de proteger um software.

Comment: vou melhorar minha pergunta

Comment: Basicamente, se você não fizer nada, já está protegido pelas leis [9609/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm) e [9610/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm).  E como não existe patente de software no Brasil, o máximo que você pode fazer é registrar no INPI para comprovar a autoria (mas existem outras formas). Você também pode escolher uma licença de software livre (mas tem vários termos nestas licenças que não são aceitos pelo sistema legal brasileiro, como a isenção de responsabilidade p.ex.), ou criar sua própria licença e registrar junto com o software.

Comment: Para ver métodos que ajudam na escolha de licenças de software livres, sugiro [este](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br) e o da [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/choose/).

Comment: @gustavox por favor informe as suas sugestões como reposta para que eu possa marcá-las como as corretas e você possa ser pontuado. Obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado, mas atente para o fato de que meu comentário não esgota o assunto. Se quiser ter certeza mesmo sobre o seu caso específico, sugiro consultar um bom advogado especializado. Não sei se é o caso de postar como resposta, pois só dei algumas dicas básicas pra vc estender sua pesquisa, mas se a pergunta não for suspensa, quando eu acabar de escrever o wiki em que estou trabalhando sobre este tema, pensarei em elaborar uma resposta mais sólida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um bom contrato que é firmado com o cliente na negociação e coloquei uma função de bloqueio que evita que a aplicação seja colocada em uma máquina que não esteja licenciada par ao uso, ou seja eu gero um arquivo criptografado com dados que são gerados por uma aplicação minha com informação geradas na máquina do cliente, que posteriormente quando o software é executado o checa se as informações coincide, assim liberando o seu uso.

Comment: Geralmente licença ou você pode criar sua própria com um contrato assinado em cartório. Ou você utiliza um já no mercado, basta incluir ele junto do software. nem precisa desenvolver algo tão complexo, porque a ideia do direito autoral é de te proteger legalmente.